# meteor allow rules

Tags: meteor, rules

I have a question on meteor's parties example.

If I call this code:

```
Parties.allow({
insert: function () {
    return true;
},

remove: function (){
    return true;    
},

update: function() {
    return true;    
}

});
```

everybody can do insert, remove and update.
The code from the example is

```
Parties.allow({
 insert: function (userId, party) {
    return false; // no cowboy inserts -- use createPage method
 },
 update: function (userId, parties, fields, modifier) {
    return _.all(parties, function (party) {
    if (userId !== party.owner)
       return false; // not the owner

  var allowed = ["title", "description", "x", "y"];
  if (_.difference(fields, allowed).length)
    return false; // tried to write to forbidden field

  // A good improvement would be to validate the type of the new
  // value of the field (and if a string, the length.) In the
  // future Meteor will have a schema system to makes that easier.
     return true;
   });
 },
 remove: function (userId, parties) {
   return ! _.any(parties, function (party) {
     // deny if not the owner, or if other people are going
     return party.owner !== userId || attending(party) > 0;
   });
 }
});
```

So my question is where the variables useriD and party at this line for example

```
 insert: function (userId, party) {
```

are defined?
Are these the variables I call in the method

```
 Meteor.call("createParty", variable1, variable2)
```

? But this wouldn't make sense because the client calls

```
 Meteor.call('createParty', {
    title: title,
    description: description,
    x: coords.x,
    y: coords.y,
    public: public
  }
```

I hope somebody can explain the allow functions to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To understand allow/deny, you need to understand where the `userId` and `doc` parameters come from. (Just as in any function definition, the actual parameter names don't matter.) Looking just at the Parties insert example:

```
Parties.allow({

  insert: function (userId, party) {
     return false; // no cowboy inserts -- use createPage method
  }

});
```

The `party` parameter is the doc that's being inserted:

```
Parties.insert(doc);
```

The `userId` parameter is set automatically IF you're using the Meteor Accounts auth system. Otherwise, you have to set it yourself on the server. How do you do that?

In general, you call code on the server from the client by using `Meteor.call()`. Since there's no built-in API to set userId (other than Accounts), you have to write your own (goes in your server code):

```
Meteor.methods({

   setUserId: function(userId) {
       this.setUserId(userId);
   }

});
```

Then you can call it like this, anywhere in your client code:

```
Meteor.call('setUserId', userId);
```

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate on the "cowboy inserts" thing? Are you saying one should never allow blanket inserts on a collection?

Comment: Not at all -- it depends on your app's business logic. That was just copy/pasted from the question.

Comment: @PhilMitchell I was just about to ask op's question until I found your great answer. I am following Discover Meteor, they show a lot of code but seldom explain what it does properly, in the example they defined the insert function with userID without ever explaining it and then passed doc without explaining that as well. This was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1) Where the variables useriD and party are defined? Nowhere! the intention is that no user can call this function.

This is in order to proctect the database from users that could insert manually new parties using the console. Remmember that Meteor replicates the database in client and server.

Any user could insert manually new parties through the console. This is fine. But then the server would reject the insert since it is not allowed.

2) Are these the variables I call in the method `Meteor.call("createParty", variable1, variable2)`? Yes the variables are available, but this code is not using the correct definition which is:

```
 Meteor.methods({
    createParty: function (options) {
```

And afterwards it is used as

```
 Meteor.call('createParty', 
            { title: title, public: public, ... }, // options array!!
            function (error, party) { ... }  // function executed after the call
 );
```

Did it help you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped, but there are some questions left:

so if I am writing
 
Parties.allow({
insert: function (userId, party) {
    return false;
}});

nobody can create a new Party by the console. But I don't get what the userId and party are standing for here? I can also write the same lines without these variables, don't I?
So no client can write a new party by console, but if the client calls the method "createParty" it can?

Comment: I agree those two variables are disturbing. I understand no insert is allowed at all. You should try some tests and check what happens.
The createParty does some checks before inserting the party, so it is ok if they use this function from the console, because those checks will be done.